# Retrieve amqp queue name within global error handler

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am implementing a global error handler in a complex system (many queues, many listeners). Inside the handling method, I need to retrieve the name of the queue the message was consumed from. Is that even possible?

**My scenario** (for full context, but feel free to ignore what follows and focus on the question only)

I want to use the global error handler to catch any non-fatal exception and enqueue the message into a "retry" exchange bound to a "retry" queue with an `x-message-ttl` of, say, a few seconds and a `x-dead-letter-exchange` set to the default exchange. I want to set the message's routing key to the queue the message came from so the default exchange will resend it to its original queue. This way all consumers will retry consuming any failed message with a delay, preventing the infamous infinite-retry loop. Hardcoding each queue manually on each consumer is obviously not suitable because there are so many consumers that the solution would be unmaintainable.

**EDIT:** if not within the error handler, is there any other amqp construct that I can use to intercept the listener and add the queue name to, for example, the message headers so that the error handler would have access to it?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I found out that the message carries information about the queue it comes from.

```java
class MyGlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  
  public void handleError(Throwable t) {
    String queueName = ((ListenerExecutionFailedException) t)
        .getFailedMessage()
        .getMessageProperties()
        .getConsumerQueue();
    // ...
  }
  
}
```